# parent with child directives won't work when creating new scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a parent directive which can retrieve data from a given URL, this works fine. 
As second step, I want to distribute the data among several child directives, such as:

```
<parent data="some/url/with/json/response">
  <child data="data[0]"></child>
  <child data="data[1]"></child>
  ...
</parent>
```

This also works fine. However, when creating another group of directives, the old data gets overwritten because the parent directive doesn't create a new scope, but overwrites everything in the main scope. When specifying one of the following lines in the directive, no data is shown at all (and now error msg appears):

```
scope: true,
//or
scope: {},
```

Here a plunker example of the faulty situation: http://plnkr.co/edit/GWcLrhaUHNLPWNkOHIS8?p=preview
The top part should have "This is working".

So the question is: Does anyone know how I can force that the parent directive creates a new scope to which all child elements have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution which also looks nice. Because plunker created a script by using angular 1.2 by default, I didn't find this solution earlier (apparently it only works in 1.3.x). Now each parent directive does create its own scope, and it's children do this also. Then, by using this notation (with $parent), the correct data is displayed:

```
<parent-bind-scope working=true>
  Should be working:
  <child-bind-scope data="$parent.working"></child-bind-scope>
</parent-bind-scope>
```

Also see: http://plnkr.co/edit/NkVxpjryD8YQm9xovw4M?p=preview

When using Remco's answer and creating an isolated scope for the children, I had to use $parent.$parent to get the same results, so it was a great step to this solution.

Addition: It's quite weird when using ng-repeat though, in my real code I now have to do **$parent.$parent.$parent** like this to get it working:

```
//not the exact code
<parent parentdata="/url/with/data">
    <div ng-repeat="i in $parent.range($parentdata.data.cols.length) track by $index">
        <child data1="$parent.$parent.$parent.parentdata.cols[$index]"
               data2="$parent.$parent.$parent.parentdata.rows[$index]"/>
    </div>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your child directive, you should evaluate the string on the parent scope, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('parentBindScope', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
      if($attrs.working) {
          $scope.working = {key: 'this is working'};
      } else {
        $scope.working = { key: 'something else' }
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.working = {key: 'this is not working'};
        },1000)

      }

    }
  }
});

app.directive('childBindScope', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>child-template: {{data}}</div>',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
      $scope.$watch('$parent.' + $attrs.data, function() {
        $scope.data = $scope.$parent.$eval($attrs.data);
      });
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(scope.data));
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
scope: false
```

In your **child scope** to preserve the scope from the parent element in child elements.

Using true or {} is called isolateScope, and there's a reason why it's like that. To protect the child scopes.

Comment: Thanks, now this kind of works, although
$scope.data=$scope.$eval($attrs.data);
isn't the best-looking code ;)

Comment: I'm sorry but I think it is still not working, this plunker shows that they still have the same scope:
http://plnkr.co/edit/22D9QMRA9gI4CmcAfJvz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent directive is inheriting scope (the controller's scope), so that all parent directives are essentially sharing the same scope.  When both parents share the same scope, the last directive to execute (the parent directive without the "working" attribute) will define the 'working' property on the shared scope, which in the link implementation, assigns $scope.working = "this is not working".

```
<!-- bind object to child scope -->
<parent-bind-scope working=true>
  Should be working: 
  <child-bind-scope data="working"></child-bind-scope>
</parent-bind-scope>

<br>

<parent-bind-scope>
  Should not be working:
  <child-bind-scope data="working"></child-bind-scope>
</parent-bind-scope>
```

If you put an alert when $scope.working is assigned, you can see that it is executing both branches of the if condition (with the else control flow, being last):

```
controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
  if($attrs.working) {
    alert('working attribute exists');
    $scope.working = {key: 'this is working'};
  } else {
    alert('working attribute does not exist');
    $scope.working = {key: 'this is not working'};
  }

}
```